# Are SharePoint development tools Visual Studio and SharePoint Designer mutually exclusive?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

We have a multi-staged development environment, comprising Development, UAT and Production systems.

When developing solutions that will be migrated across all environments, we would like to be able to take advantage of all of the available development tools, including the SharePoint UI, SharePoint Designer and Visual Studio.

My question is, are the tools mutually exclusive?
Is it possible to create some components like Lists and Views using the UI and Designer, and then use visual Studio to create more complex features like web parts?
If so is there a specific process that you need to follow to make sure all of the tools play with each other for your solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience... if it's possible to do in the UI, do it there.  If it's not possible to do in the UI, but it can be done in Designer, do it there.  If it's not possible in either the UI or Designer, then and only then, should it be done in Visual Studio.

> If so is there a specific process that you need to follow to make sure all of the tools play with each other for your solution?

this is a important, but not easy to answer.  For instance, I developed a custom web part that stored info in a list.  At any point, a site owner could modify or delete the list from the UI and my web part would fail...  to this day that's the way it is.  It's a classic content management system conundrum, allow users to do their job while prohibiting them from breaking stuff.  good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How would you go about combining your changes in the UI and Designer with a Visual Studio solution?

Comment: for the most part, VS solutions are pieces of a puzzle that contribute to the overall.  sharepoint is basically a bunch of components combined.  you could start with a document library - basic OOB feature (UI), stick it on a page that maybe has a custom page layout (Designer), then you need to give the user the ability to contribute a doc - but you have a requirement that just isn't possible via the default behavior - you need to rename the file to meet legal requirement, etc... then you need a custom web part (VS) to handle that.  let me know if that helps &/or makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense, but I am interested in HOW you integrate those UI and Designer changes with a VS solution.  And after you integrate can you still make changes in the UI and Designer or are you stuck with VS to make changes from that point onwards?

Comment: You can continue to change the page via the UI or Designer after a VS solution is added.  I'm thinking of a page with a VS developed web part on it.  Say there's a content editor web part on the page with a welcome message, that can be edited via the UI.  But if a change is needed to the VS web part, you'll need to go back to visual studio, change the code, package it, then redeploy.  Sandboxed solutions make that a little easier, but that's for another day.  You could have a little cross-over via CSS, a CSS file that you can edit in designer but use the styles in your web part.